# How set item id and item value to Spinner?

Tags: android, database, spinner, adapter

I got a data base with table 'cars'. In this table two columns id and name. im loading data from database and set to spinner. But i setting up only name column to spinner. Im trying put there id too. How i can set to adapter id and name, when select spinner item i must get this id to getting another data from database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `View`'s `setTag()` and `getTag()` methods to set and get id.

If suddenly you are using `ArrayAdapter` instead of `CursorAdapter` for database data, <strike>please stop doing it</strike> you could simply get the element by selection index from inner data collection.